# Alternative to Cloudflare tunnel if I can't open port 7844 and no root access on hosting server

Tags: port, vpn, cloudflare, portforwarding, tunnel

I have a linux server hosting an app that I want to expose using my namecheap domain name.

The network that the linux server is behind *seems* to be blocking port 7844, docker error:

"ERR Serve tunnel error error="DialContext error: dial tcp xxx:7844: i/o timeout" connIndex=0 ip=xxx

ERR Unable to establish connection with Cloudflare edge error="DialContext e rror: dial tcp xxx.:7844: i/o timeout" connIndex=0 ip=xxx.33
"

Works fine on machines on another network, linux and windows. So looks to be the network, which I can't port forward on.

I found SirTunnel: https://github.com/anderspitman/SirTunnel but this requires sudo on my siteground server, which isn't possible.

Are there any free alternatives I can use? Or a way I can use cloudflare through a different port?

Thanks

Comment: will the network allow Cloudflare tunnel to work on any ports? that would be the first test i would try before deciding to ditch Cloudflare tunnels.

Comment: @JoeBourne thanks for the reply. However, as far as I know I can't change the port that cloudflare uses, unless I'm mistaken? I could redirect ports on the linux machine, however I can't make cloudflare use a different port.